# Passing options to a function

Tags: python

In ruby it is idiomatic to write a function that may be called like this:

```
open_database(:readonly) // or
open_database(:readonly, :remote, :force)
```

In these cases the :readonly are "symbols" and are used as "flags" to modify the behavior of the open_database call.

We would implement this as follows in ruby:

```
def func(*params)
  if params.include? :readonly
    puts "readonly"
  end
end
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Python?

Comment: out of curiosity, what does the argument-handling implementation look like in Ruby?  I mean, though @Mattias answer rings true, you could be getting an *args in Python and doing "readonly" in *args - this would preserve your calling example  format, so knowing what Ruby does is nice.

Comment: See edited original question

Comment: interesting.  M's answer w unpacking does offer the same syntactic sugar but the _custom_ around Python API/function signature design, i.e how most systems present to the outside is very much as per his keyword call - I've never seen anything wanting passing string flags in.

Answer (score 8):

There is no such syntactic sugar on Python.

---

The correct way to do this would be to use default keyword arguments:

```
def open_database(readonly=False, remote=False, force=False):
   # ...
```

You can then:

```
open_database(readonly=True, force=True) # remote=False (default)
```

---

If you want to get as close as possible to ruby, you can do argument unpacking:

```
def specify_flags(*args):
    return {x: True for x in args}

open_database(**specify_flags('readonly', 'force')) # Same as readonly=True, force=True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which is almost exactly what you want:

```
In [1]: def open_database(**kwargs):
   ...:     if 'readonly' in kwargs:
   ...:         print 'Setting up read only'
   ...:     if 'remote' in kwargs:
   ...:         print 'Setting up remote'
   ...:         

In [2]: open_database()

In [3]: open_database(remote=0)
Setting up remote

In [4]:
```

You just have to specify a value for the keyword argument. Note that this could actually come in handy later, but is not pretty if you really don't need it.